# How to automate read/download/upload files to SP365 with VBA

Tags: sharepoint-online

The old Sharepoint allowed to read, download and upload files automatically. We have automated processes that get daily files for SP, make calulations in Excel with the data from SP, and upload resulting reports back onto SP. With the new SP, these programs fail. I have spend most of the past two weeks in looking for ways or people who can write the VBA script to overcome this problem.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Johan you need to be more specific about your issue (ie you have problems connecting, downloading the files with example of VB script that you are using). It seems you have automated process without the right resources to support it (VB script programmer) so you need to either get someone on board or recreate the process in language you can support (like PowerShell). As you issue is not SHarepoint related you may have more luck on some VBs forums.

Comment: Please find the actual code herunder:

Answer (score 0):

According to this [other question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/253340/8992), it is possible to access SharePoint's REST API from VBA code.

I have no experience with VBA, so I can't elaborate on any details of how to actually do it, but it does seem that it is possible to make HTTP requests form VBA code, and therefore accessing SharePoint's REST API should be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the actual code here-under:
Sub BLGet_NewBLData() ''NEW SITE
    Dim Path As String
    Dim BLfile As String
    Dim DirName As String
    Dim Temp As String
    Dim DTResult As Date
    Dim Yesterday As Date

Sheets("Buttons").Select

' I tried with HTTPS and without.
'Path = "https://myfedex.sharepoint.com/teams/SFOTI/GFMC/BacklogReportField/"
Path = "//myfedex.sharepoint.com/teams/SFOTI/GFMC/BacklogReportField/"

BLfile = Path
        ChDir Path
        BLfile = Dir(Path & "*.*")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

```
    Do While BLfile <> ""
    Temp = BLfile
```

DTResult = FileDateTime(Path & BLfile)
Yesterday = Now() - 1
            If DTResult > Yesterday Then
                Workbooks.Open FileName:=Path & BLfile, Password:="", ReadOnly:=True
            BLfile = Temp

BLCP_BLData

```
        Else: GoTo SKIP

        End If
```

SKIP:
        BLfile = Dir
        Loop

Windows("BacklogProgram.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Backlog").Select

End Sub